# Rollback changes for only one of commited files

Tags: git

What if I have commited several files: file1.txt, file2.txt and file3.txt at once. Then I decided that I need to roll back all changes I made for file1.txt. How to do so?

Comment: Do you want to create a new commit rolling back the change to file1.txt, or do you want to edit the original commit (change history) to leave out the change to file1.txt?

Comment: Can you list both cases please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the file to a state before the commit. For this, you need the hash of the commit before the changes and use the following command

```
git checkout hash file1.txt
```

Or you can undo the commit with `git reset HEAD^` and do the commit without adding file1.txt

Comment: What does git reset HEAD^ do?

Comment: It undo the last commmit, putting all changes in modified files or untracked files state.

Comment: @siik Specifically `git reset HEAD` would reset the working directory to last commit, reverting any changes currently made. `^` operator means "one commit before lhs operand".

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice link here about [undoing things in git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things).

If you just committed and want to undo something in your last commit, you can use

```
git commit --amend
```

If you want to undo the changes made on a file and put it back in its original state before the commit you can use

```
git checkout <number> <file>
```